# How to know some app's console command in unity dash?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-unity

Is it possible to see some app's console command from unity dash menu?

For example, I open the Dash via the windows key, type in some app name, it appears in the list below, and I do "something" to see how to start it from the command line.

I am asking this because I came across multiple 3rd party apps whose console command has nothing with the app name, and I was unable to figure out how to open such apps from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to this path in a file manager: `/usr/share/applications`

For example, with Nautilus you would run (in a terminal)

```
nautilus /usr/share/applications
```

Locate your program by name (using search if required).

Right click the file for your program.
Select 'Properties'.
There should be a 'Command' field which shows the command to be executed. If the program has arguments such as %U, those are file arguments passed when that program is used to open a file.